# Local xampp wordpress installation - cannot find wp-blog-header.php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, xampp

I'm working locally with XAMPP and Wordpress and I'm struggling with what is probably a very basic config issue. I'm not a professional IT guy, just a hobbyist hacker so I apologise in advance if I'm being a bit dumb but hopefully somebody can kindly offer some assistance here.

I've installed xampp locally on my iMac. I've then installed wordpress using the xampp wordpress installation package. Both seem to be working fine. To test the web server I created a simple .php test file and this generated the expected output when I entered "localhost/hello.php" into my browser. As far as wordpress is concerned entering "localhost/wordpress" gives me access the local wp interface to create and edit posts, change display settings etc etc. So far so good...

Now I want to create a new .php file that includes the instruction:

require('XXX/wp-blog-header.php') 
where the "XXX" is obviously the relevant directory path for the wp header file.

I cannot find this file, or indeed local wordpress files, anywhere (and I've searched extensively). In the "home" location for "localhost" (which I know from my "hello.php" test) there isn't even a wordpress directory so I'm totally puzzled as to how typing "localhost/wordpress" in my browser is accessing the local wp installation or how to go about determining the correct directory path for the wp header file I'm looking for?

I do understand that with this stack a great deal of info will either be generated on the fly, or stored in the local mysql database as opposed to the file structure, but I thought I would find some reference or alias somewhere to help me trace this through and determine what path to include in my .php file for wp-blog-header.php.

I've searched this forum and while there are several related questions I haven't found anything that helps me with this particular issue.

Thanks vm,

Ian

Comment: just search for wp_load, but usually your installation files will be in a folder called htdocs in xampp or in a folder you have an apache vh set up for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the path I needed and (partially) understand why I couldn't locate it. As Scriptonomy helped me identify the Wordpress files are held at:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress

While my test.php file is held at:

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php

The reason I couldn't locate either wp-blog-header.php or wp-load.php is because these there is an another "htdocs" sub-dir under the wordpress install location i.e.:

../apps/wordpress/htdocs

However I (as user "admin") don't have access to read this directory and so couldn't see the contents and therefore couldn't find the files. The permissions on the directory belong to "daemon" which I guess was the XAMPP installer package? Setting the directory path in my test.php file to:

../apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-load.php

somehow the web server (?) can read the file (even though I can't see it myself via the Finder application) and so the code is now giving the expected result.

So problem solved even if I don't quite understand the solution!

Thanks for replies which helped me eventually get to a solution!

Cheers,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

The location of your Wordpress files is:

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress`

Comment: Thanks. I do see this directory but still can't find wp-blog-header.php or wp_load (as per the comment added by David above). To be very precise I have created test file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php & my wordpress files are at /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/apps/wordpress (which you've helped me to locate!). Putting the single command phpinfo(); into my test.php file and typing "localhost/test.php" into my browser works ok. But if I add require('XXX/wp-blog-header.php') to the test file I can't find a value for XXX that doesn't throw a "failed to open stream: No such.." error.